# Why does TypeScript allow implicit downcast in method parameters?

Tags: typescript, downcast

Here is the example:

```js
interface Vehicle{
    mass:number
}
interface InspectorClass{
    inspect(v:Vehicle):void
}


class Car implements Vehicle{
    mass = 2000
    wheels = 4
}
class Boat implements Vehicle{
    mass = 3000
    sails = 2
}


// with methods it silently fails:

class BoatInspector implements InspectorClass{
    inspect(v:Boat){ // interface contract silently violated!!!
        console.log(v.mass)
        console.log(v.sails)
    }
}

function runInspection(inspector:InspectorClass, vehicle:Vehicle){
    inspector.inspect(vehicle)
}

let myCar = new Car()
let myBoatInspector = new BoatInspector()
runInspection(myBoatInspector, myCar)


// with functions it checks properly:

type InspectorFunction = (v:Vehicle) => void

const inspectCar:InspectorFunction = function(v:Car){ // TypeScript complains as it should
    console.log(v.mass)
    console.log(v.wheels)
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGoQBbAQGwgbwChkTkBbOAZ0oC4QBXMgI2kIF9DRJZEUBJEJQAOEBGAD2UAMI4qlIqWShhosAAoAbjXRZcEAJQ0N44ABN2hS7jnIpcKErJC8ZCOEppM2PAtIVqyAC8yABMAAwRxKQA7hgQEDgewQAsFtYBAELicGCOzhCu7p66PlEk-knIAMwRYWXIlHDAiUGhFpYA9B3I0cBgGOQQ-eKmHn0NzW5gOACeyPDNtFaymdlgAipiknkuUx4bIlvSK-L1yofqWlk5%20vjIXUrg0PBIyAji4FCIuZST4LPIDTAcSySCmACEkPqineghBEAAdDhxABzTQIir6aGkWGUeFI1HoxqLLGKDgcQgweggMTAkDIKDUg6qOlqc6qSQ0ZlHGRyAA0gK8em0QrwtzOggukgR7LEmlFBnaeFyZBmdgcwRAEGitnsaixyvIM2u60lHI1yC1OpN3IkUH1hEZIFtrNVNrNRwFqvVWM63V6-Xm1NpHzGuQQcQQAGsPEIoOIRFBZjRLGAZiJkLbJAAxYNgOmtTQikoGIIAPkBJnMhFxuVlYHVXI9dtzNPzH1aVLbrK0PruDwAKumIABlBBQYBCcPiJyyZTIKhKH4YcT0HDmGGh-HItEaDFyUk4rd4Am7hGxeKJLEcIA)

The contract of the interface states that an inspect method in an InspectorClass instance has to be able to inspect any kind of Vehicle. Why does TypeScript let me implement a class that actually only accepts Boats without complaining? Is this a bug? Or is it by design for some reason? Or can I enable this with some flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked duplicate explains the situation.  For your code above, the fix is probably to use `--strictFunctionTypes` and write your method signature as a function-valued-property signature:

```
interface InspectorClass{
    inspect: (v:Vehicle) => void
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGoQBbAQGxQbwChkTkBbOAZ0oC5kQBXMgI2kIF9DRJZEUBJEJQAOEBGAD2UAMI4qlZEVLJQIsWDoAKAG510WXBACUyALwA+ZNonAAJh0KPc85NLhQVZYXjIRwC-Ww8RWJSCmozZAAmAAY40JIAdwwICBwFU2QAFgdnCIAhCTgwT28IX380TCCCBPIXTIBmOJi6yjhgdMioh0cAej7kROAwDHIIUYlbBRHkSk6-MBwAT2R4TtonOQKisEE1cSlSn0WFfdFDmW2FJVJVC7AdOkLik3xkAZVwaHgkZAQJOAoIgSvM8OAVlZgBI5JBbABCRF1ZQAoQwiAAOhwEgA5joMeFKEZkaRUZR0Vjcfj2hticpOJxCDAGCBxNCQMgoCzzup2Zp7uopHQeZdZPIADRWaqGPTSvBvOoCy4YpWPbRy4y9PAlMjLNweTIgCCJVzuTTE7XkZYvPZCB5HQ3G5A2kWSKDmwhckCuvm6l12wVQSW6-XE-qDYajNYstmAmYlBApBAAawUwigElEUBWNEcYGWomQrqkADEY2B2ZEnlUDPKzJZrHYnHGSqr9cKA5cy6yK4DIsye5Xq6HFB9BgAVAsQADKCCgwGECYkXjkqmQVBUoIwEgYOHsKLjFOxeO0BPkdNJh7wlJPGOSqXSxM4QA)